# can't access rpmfusion.org via HTTPS

Tags: fedora, rpm

I want to download the free and nonfree versions of rpmfusion, but, much to my surprise, the site runs only on HTTP. What can I do to make sure no third party has compromised the downloads? I've tried accessing https://rpmfusion.org via Windows and Fedora 22.

Answer (score 3):

If a website only runs HTTP you won't be able to access it in HTTPS, no matter how hard you try.

However, you don't need HTTPS to ensure package integrity.  Each RPM is digitally signed to ensure no third party has tampered its contents. FYI, [the GPG keys for RPM Fusion are here](http://rpmfusion.org/keys) and they'll be automatically installed [when you download and install the RPM that enables the RPM Fusion repo](http://rpmfusion.org/Configuration).

Comment: I think the GPG keys are added automatically when you use the repo RPMs from [here](http://rpmfusion.org/Configuration) to set up Rpmfusion.

Comment: Good point, I forgot to specify that.  Added to answer.

Comment: That would be fine if at least rpmfusion.org/keys was available over HTTPS.  But it's HTTP only, so how can I know I'm trusting the right keys?

Comment: Reasonable consolation: [searching https://pgp.mit.edu](https://pgp.mit.edu/pks/lookup?search=RPM+Fusion+free+repository+for+Fedora+%2823%29&op=index&fingerprint=on) returns one match, with same fingerprint.